# google test: MOCK_METHODn (old style) - function with char** argument

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I am using old version of google test, using MOCK_METHODn (old style) macros. I am trying to create a mock method for a virtual function with char** argument and receive compilation errors.

Does anyone have example for mocking "**" arguments ?

Comment: You should provide the relevant parts of your code and the exact compilation errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for this issue, it was not related to the usage of char**. I was using MOCK_METHODn which expected 6 arguments, and in EXPECT_CALL statement I was using "Invoke" call to a function which received smaller number of arguments. There was an inconsistency between the signature of the invoked function and MOCK_METHODn.